# How to use datatables' api on Yajra service

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, yajra-datatable

We use Yajra package and `app/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php` file in our laravel project. In this file, how to define `$.fn.dataTable.moment()`? For example, look at the image below:

[image]